# Sequence of sequences with sup-norm goes to 0 but 2-norm stay positive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lp-spaces

I am trying to show sup-norm is strictly weaker than 2-norm in sequence space. In $\Bbb R^n$, we have sup-norm equivalent to 2-norm since we are doing finite sum, $\sqrt{\sum^Na_n^2}\le\sqrt{\sum^N||a_n||_\infty^2}=\sqrt N||a_n||_\infty$. But, in sequence space, we have infinitely many terms, I think it is possible to keep the sup-norm very low but the 2-norm say positive. Therefore, we can find a sequence of sequences converges to 0 in supnorm but stay positive in 2-norm. But I got stuck in finding such an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of sequences defined as follows
\begin{align*}
x_1 & = (1,0,0\cdots)\\
x_2 & = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\cdots)\\
x_3 & = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},0,\cdots)\\
&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\vdots\\
x_n & = (\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt n},\frac{1}{\sqrt n},\cdots,\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}_{\text{first }n \:\text{terms}},0,0\cdots)\\
&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\vdots\\
\lvert\lvert x_n\rvert\rvert_\infty&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \:\:\text{but}\:\:\lvert\lvert x_n\rvert\rvert_2 =1
\end{align*}

Comment: This gave me notational whiplash, it looks like a finite list of $n$ elements but its actually an infinite list + 1, and the last element is not like the others!

Comment: @CalvinKhor I have edited my answer. Please have a look.