# A question about the $||\cdot ||_{\infty}$ and $||\cdot ||_{2}$ norms in $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm a little curious to understand the $||\cdot ||_{\infty}$ and $||\cdot ||_{2}$ norms a little better.

The following [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3930166/sequence-of-sequences-with-sup-norm-goes-to-0-but-2-norm-stay-positive) presents a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $\ell^2$ that is in the unit ball, but $|| x_n ||_{\infty} \to 0$, as $n \to \infty$.

More specifically, the first $n$ elements (or coordinates) of $x_n$ are equal to $1/\sqrt{n}$. So, we can consider this example a little "simple".

I would like to know if we can construct a sequence $(x_n)$ such that
$$||x_n ||_{2}> r, \,\, \forall n \in \mathbb N, \quad r>0$$
and $|| x_n ||_{\infty} \to 0$, as $n \to \infty$, but the non-null coordinates $x_{jn}$'s that make up $x_n$ are not all the same?

Does the number of non-zero elements $x_{jn}$ necessarily have to be finite or can we have infinitely many non-zero coordinates? (Remember that we necessarily have to have $|x_{jn}|^2 \to 0$, as $j \to \infty$ for all $n$).

Comment: Zeros don't play a major role in that example. You can easily get rid of zeros. Just add  $e^{-k}$ (for example), to the $k-$th term of each $x_n$ and then  normalize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $x_{jn} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n + 1}(\frac{n}{n + 1})^{j - 1}}$ gives you an example. $||x_n||_2 = 1$ for all $n$ but $||x_n||_\infty = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n + 1}} \rightarrow 0$.